# C# number decimal place fix

Tags: c#, numbers

Hey guys I have a number that is lets say 1.5 I want it to be 1.50

```
private double FixDecimals(double data)
    {
        double tmpDouble = Convert.ToDouble(String.Format("{0:0.00}", data));
        return tmpDouble;
    }
```

This is the real function and it doesn't seem to be working. Please pass 1.5 to it and tell me what you get.

Comment: Why the downvote?  It seems like a perfectly reasonable question where the OP has shown an attempt at a solution and does not understand why the attempt did not work.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps the OP could tell us more than "this doesn't seem to be working".  Does it throw an Exception, does it produce undesirable output... etc.

Comment: I'm not distributing my source code i'm asking for a simple function that is capable of doing this. Clearly that isn't working. I'm trying to make a double show 2 decimal places.

Comment: Oh golly, I just saw it.  It looks like you're using a number format string "{0:0.00}" in String.Format, whereas those are supposed to be used in Double.Format.  What type is Object variable?

Comment: @TheCryptKeeper: The suggestion is valid to edit your question adding more detail about what you are actually seeing.  "doesn't seem to work" is pretty vague...

Comment: this is pretty simple to figure out what he `OP` is trying to do and or accomplish .. the string.Format function does not require the arg to be of type string which is where he may have made his negative assumption.. @TheCryptKeeper just google in your spare time string.Format function msdn for further clarification and examples

Comment: @TheCryptKeeper good question but in the future try to add as much relevant detail in regards to your problem and or issue(s) just saying it doesn't work will usually generate a lot of negative chatter.. how the working examples help.. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `ToString` on `variable`:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", variable)
```

Assuming `variable` is of type `double`, `variable.ToString()` is formatting the double with the "G" format specifier, giving you `1.5`. Then *that* value is passed to `string.Format`.

---

**Update after question edit:**

A variable of type `double` has no real format except when converted to a `string`. Because of this, the `FixDecimals` function doesn't really make sense.

As far as variables of type `double` are concerned, 1.5 is equal to 1.5000. If you want to control how that value is displayed, convert it to a `string` first.

Answer (score 1):

look at the example you do not need the .ToString() when using string.Format

```
var variable = 1.5;
var frmtString = String.Format("{0:0.00}", variable);
```

frmtString = `1.50`

This would also have yielded the same result

```
var mydouble = 1.5;
var frmtString = String.Format("{0:N}", mydouble);
```

Answer (score 0):

A `double` is a double, and if you have a double that is 1.5, it is computationally equivalent to 1.50 (and however many extra zeros to add). So when you view it in the debugger, its taking the double and converting it to a readable string using the default ToString formatter.

As the other answers say, if you want to *print it out* then you can add decimal places, but there is no need (nor does it work) to add them in code like you are trying to do by converting a double to a string and back to a double again with "extra decimal places".

Comment: my solution was data.toString("0.00")

Comment: @TheCryptKeeper can you show your "Solution" data.toString("0.00"); is not valid syntax is that a typo in `toString`